# ngrx with boolean type

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a state in Ngrx with a piece of boolean data:

```
export interface MyState {
    success?: boolean;
}

const initialState: MyState = { };

export const success = createSelector(myFeatureSelector, state => state.success);
```

So if I do the following:

```
myStateStore.select(success).subscribe(success => {
    // this will only emit if the state changes
});
```

So say if I dispatch 2 actions in sequence and both of them set the state to `true`, only the first one will emit a success value the 2nd one won't because the value is not changed. Is there a way to emit regardless?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add `changeCount` property to your state (which would get incremented on each change (or success)

```js
export interface MyState {
  success?: boolean;
  changeCount: number;
}
```

Then change your code as following:

```js
this.myStateStore
.pipe(
  select(changeCount),
  mergeMapTo(this.myStateStore.select(success))
)
.subscribe(success => {
 
});
```

Comment: really smart! i will see if anyone else can come up with a different idea. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand why `selectors` is not returning the value. Selectors are `Memoized` and does not execute if the value does not change.
There is a way to skip the `memoization`

```
myStateStore.select(success).subscribe(success => {
    // this will only emit if the state changes
});

success.release(); // This will force the selector to not memoized.
```

Comment: I tried it before I post my question here but sometimes the value doesn't seem to clear. Maybe I can give it another try to see if I stuffed up anything in my code.